# NodeJS + CoffeeScript, render coffeescript compiled js on request

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

What I would like to do is add the following to me already running coffeescript written server

```
app.get '/test.js', (req, res) ->
    render coffee somecoffeefile.coffee
```

Is something like this possible with NodeJS, Express, and Coffeescript?

Thanks!

Jose

Answer (score 30):

Good news: This is already comes with Connect (and therefore Express, which extends Connect) as a plugin! It's not well-documented; in fact, I wrote something similar myself ([connect-coffee](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-coffee)) before I was informed that such a thing already existed.

Here's how you'd go about setting it up with Express:

```
# Notice the following code is coffescript
# You must add the parens for the app.use method to use in js
coffeeDir = __dirname + '/coffee'
publicDir = __dirname + '/public'
app.use express.compiler(src: coffeeDir, dest: publicDir, enable: ['coffeescript'])
app.use express.static(publicDir)
```

Now when, say, `http://yourapp/foo.js` gets requested, if no such file exists in your `public` directory, `foo.coffee` will automatically be compiled, and the resulting `foo.js` will be served. Note that it's important for `static` to be set up *after* `compiler`.

**Update:** As of Connect 1.7, the `compiler` middleware has been removed. Partly because of that, and partly to provide a more Rails 3.1-like experience, I've created a new middleware called [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets). Install it with npm, then set it up like so:

```
app.use require('connect-assets')(directory)
```

where `directory` is the folder your CoffeeScript files are in (the default is `assets`). Simple, right? Try it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: Trevor, I am getting an error with this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Object.compiler [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/middleware/compiler.js:58:19)

Comment: You need to define `coffeeDir`, e.g. `coffeeDir = __dirname + '/scripts'` if your `.coffee` files are in the `scripts` subdirectory. Note that the directory path isn't added to the URL. So if you had a file at `scripts/foo.coffee`, you would request `http://localhost/foo.js` to get the compiled JavaScript.

Comment: In the newer versions of connect, `staticProvider()` is now called `static()`. Also, for security, if you don't want people to be able to get your original `*.coffee` files, you should set both `dest` and `src` in the call to `compiler()`. They should not be the same. `src` is where your original `*.coffee` files are located, and `dest` is the static directory where they are compiled to.

Comment: Thanks, Amir! I've edited my answer to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: This does not work for me. Is there a new update that disabled this? It's not throwing an error, but it just not finding client.js (which should look for client.coffee and compile it).

Comment: I think I diagnosed the problem, it looks like if your request looks in a directory `<script src = "/javascript/client.js"></script>` it won't recognize to compile it. When I just do `<script src = "client.js"></script>` it compiles it but cannot find it. So I compile it using that, then have to change it back to /javascript/client.js in order for it to work..

Comment: Well, woops. This is treated just like static. If you have subdirectories, connect will look inside them on the server. So, `/javascript/client.js` will be searched for in `public/javascript/client.js`. I had source be in `public/javascript/` not simply `public/` so I was getting `public/javascript/javascript/client.js`.

Comment: @Matt, I'm facing the same problem. it seem no matter what directory I set for the dest,

Comment: love `connect-assets`.  Is it possible to add variables from `app.locals` into a file `assets/js/myfile.coffee`?  So in `app.coffee` I have `app.locals.socketio_url = 'http://localhost'` and after calling `js('myfile')` I would like `<%- socketio_url %>` to be there.  Right now it says `Parse error: Unexpected 'MATH'`.  I understand that it is trying to compile the ejs template tag and that is throwing the error.  So I am wondering what is the proper way to get a variable from the app.coffee into the compiled coffeescript?

Answer (score 12):

```
CoffeeScript = require 'coffee-script'

app.get '/test.js', (req, res) ->
  render CoffeeScript.compile coffeeSourceCode
```

Comment: In this case, "coffeeSourceCode" is the actual source code, not a pathname. I added a separate answer to compile from a file.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, the compiler isn't working anymore, so I did this:

```
fs = require 'fs'
coffee = require 'coffee-script'

app.use express.static "#{__dirname}/static"

app.get '/:script.js', (req, res) ->
  res.header 'Content-Type', 'application/x-javascript'
  cs = fs.readFileSync "#{__dirname}/coffee/#{req.params.script}.coffee", "ascii"
  js = coffee.compile cs 
  res.send js
```

Now you can code up coffee/animal.coffee and in your html, do a standard script src='/animal.js'. This hides the implementation detail. The coffeescript is not accessible because "/coffee" dir is not exposed as a static path.

Notes:

1. This is, of course, a CoffeeScript Node app. I assume if you're using CS for client scripts, you're using it for your server too!
2. The "static" line is optional. My point is you can happily keep "js" files in the static dir, e.g. library files like jquery.min.js.
3. Like most Node/Express examples, this is good for development; but for production, you should send cache headers, compress it, and ideally some form of reverse-proxying to avoid reading the file and compiling it each time.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a new version of Connect, which no longer has the compiler middleware. See my updated answer.

Comment: I also got this from the CoffeeScript twitter account:
"@mahemoff Yeah, the compiler middleware is gone in the latest Connect/Express. Working on an alternative..."

https://twitter.com/#!/CoffeeScript/status/107080947706503168

Comment: Yeah, I run the CoffeeScript Twitter account. [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) is the alternative I was referring to. :)

Comment: Ah :). Do you have any plans to support a production configuration? I did some custom coding for a production deployment, because I wanted to combine scripts (as well as stylesheets) and run a compressor on them. Could do with a standard way to do that in Connect/Express. (Happy to share my code, though it's far from generalized.)

Comment: It's definitely something that I want to support eventually. In fact, the docs say "In 2.0, connect-assets will also provide a way to concatenate and minify these files for production (à la Sprockets)."

Answer (score 6):

For those of us using the latest version of Connect and Express, I've just published a new module, [npm install connect-coffee-script](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-connect-coffee-script), which compile coffee script files on the fly. Documentation and a sample are provided as well as an [introduction article](http://www.adaltas.com/blog/2012/07/24/coffee-script-connect-middleware/).

Here's an exemple from the readme:

```
    var coffeescript = require('connect-coffee-script');
    var connect = require('connect');

    var app = connect();

    app.use(coffeescript({
        src: __dirname,
        dest: __dirname + '/public',
        bare: true
    }));

    app.use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: As a reply to the-teacher, all those middlewares will compile Coffee files only once, when a modification occur. The only cost is to get the modification time of the file and in production mode, a plugin like connect-coffee-script can simply be commented as the js file is already generated on the disk.

Comment: I'm really confused - how do I use this with express?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use a great existing plugin I would recommend [Trevor Burnham's Connect-Assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets). It helps compiling, minifying and concatenating .js and .coffee-files and optimizes how the files are being served (a far-future expires header with invalidation using the file's md5-hash). Well written plugin.

Comment: +1 For being the only one in the list recommending systematic asset management system. Connect-assets has a new home : https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets

Answer (score 2):

[coffee-middleware](https://www.npmjs.org/package/coffee-middleware) did exactly what I wanted to - minimal setup, no generated files, and not sloppy.
When it gets a request for `somescript.js` it will check if there is a `somescript.coffee`. If there is, it will compile it and send it over.

Install it:

```
npm install coffee-middleware
```

To use, just add

```
app.use require('coffee-middleware') src: "#{__dirname}/your/web/root"
```

before whatever you use to serve static files.

Simple example that serves files in a "public" directory, complies coffeescript before sending it over, and does colored logging:

```
app = require('express')()

app.use require('morgan') 'dev'
app.use require('coffee-middleware') src: "#{__dirname}/views"
app.use require('serve-static') "#{__dirname}/views"
app.listen 80
```

To use above code:

```
mkdir coffeeServer
cd coffeeServer
npm install morgan coffee-middleware serve-static
npm install coffee-script -g

echo 'app = require("express")()
app.use require("morgan") "dev"
app.use require("coffee-middleware") src: "#{__dirname}/views"
app.use require("serve-static") "#{__dirname}/views"
app.listen 80' > server.coffee

coffee -c server.coffee
mkdir views
cd views
echo 'console.log "Hello world!"' > script.coffee
cd ..
node server.js
```

You can copy the whole bunch into the terminal and it will setup and run the server.

To test:

```
curl XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/script.js
```

That last bit should spit out

```
(function() {
  console.log("Hello world!");

}).call(this);

//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoic2NyaXB0LmpzIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyJzY3JpcHQuY29mZmVlIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBO0FBQUEsRUFBQSxPQUFPLENBQUMsR0FBUixDQUFZLGNBQVosQ0FBQSxDQUFBO0FBQUEifQ==NHS0076
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use [Coffee4Clients](https://github.com/balupton/coffee4clients.npm) to render coffee assets to javascript on the fly with your express server.</s>

Update: Coffee4Clients has been killed in favour of [DocPad](http://docpad.org) which pre-compiles your assets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should compile COFFEE files **only once**, especially with production mode

If you want use **coffee with Express 3**, or with any web framework look to this repo [ExpressOnSteroids](https://github.com/the-teacher/ExpressOnSteroids) You can use this solution, or create your own with [Cakefile](https://github.com/the-teacher/ExpressOnSteroids/blob/master/Cakefile) from this project